# Some doubts about how make an image clickable using CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am studying on a tutorial how to create a tabless web template using HTML + CSS and I have a little doubt related to the following thing:

I have an header that contains a **div having id=logo**, something like this:

```html
        <div id="header">    <!-- HEADER -->
            <div id="logo">     <!-- My Logo -->
                <h1><a href="#">My web site is cool</a></h1>
                <p id="slogan">
                    My web site is finally online
                </p>
            </div>
                            ......
                            OTHER HEADER STUFF
                            ......
        </div> <!-- Close header -->
```

And related to this **#header** div (and its content) I have the following CSS code:

```css
/* For the image replacement of the logo */
h1 {
    background: url(../images/logo.jpg) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 224px;
    height: 71px;
}

h1 a {
    display: block;
    width: 258px;
    height: 64px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So this code put an image instead of the **My web site is cool** text that is in the  tag.

I have some problem to understand the **h1 a** CSS settings, on the tutorial say that this CSS settings **for h1 a**:

**Turns to block (from inline) the display mode of the link in the header, so I can set the width and height, and the image of the logo is now clickable**

This thing is not very clear for me and I have the following doubts:

Have I to convert the a element (that is inline) into a block element to give it the same dimension of the underlying image (logo.jpg)?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this example,

an `a` element is `inline` by default, so if you were to do something like

CSS

```
a {background:red; height:210px; width:200px;}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#">test</a>
```

You will notice that the `width` and `height` properties aren't working. Now for this element to be sized at that width, you need to set the element's display property to be either `display:block` or `display:inline-block`

**[JSFiddle Demo Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nickr/baKea/)**

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#">Without display:inline block, width and height set.</a>
<br><br>
<a href="#" class="inline-block">With display:inline block, width and height set.</a>
<br><br>
<a href="#" class="block">With display:block, width and height set.</a>
```

**CSS**:

```
a {background:#ccc; height:210px; width:200px;}
.inline-block { display:inline-block; }
.block { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're linking an image, you don't need to give the `a` height/width or even a `display:block`. However, you really shouldn't be putting an image inside an `h1` like that. You'd be better off making the `a` inside the `h1` a block (using `display:block`) and setting the background to the image, then hiding the text. To the user of the site, there's not going to be much difference, but it removes images from your HTML code, makes it easier for screen readers, and is more semantically correct. So your code would be:

```
a { display: block; font-size:0; background-image:url("logo.png"); height:100; width:100 }
```